# oracle between month name

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause, between

My output without where clause ( sample )

| ID | NAMEN | NAME | BEGINN | ENDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108129 | Kürbis, Gartenkürbis, Feldkürbis | Blüten | Juli | Juli |
| 126611 | Nussbaum, Walnuss, Christnuss | Schalen | August | September |
| 126611 | Nussbaum, Walnuss, Christnuss | Früchte | Oktober | Oktober |
| 126611 | Nussbaum, Walnuss, Christnuss | Blätter | Juni | Juni |
| 92542 | Beifuß Stabkraut, Besenkraut | Blätter | Juni | Juni |
| 92542 | Beifuß Stabkraut, Besenkraut | Wurzeln | September | November |

Hi i try to select entries between **beginn** (e.g Juli) and **ende** (e.g. Dezember) (varchar2).

```
select * from (
    select * from VIEW_USER_CON_PFLANZE_ERNTE
    )
where sysdate 
between to_date(beginn, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German')
and to_date(ende, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German')
```

but i get the error: **ORA-01843: not a valid month**

at the end, i want to realize this:

```
where sysdate
...
and last_day(to_date(ende, 'DD.MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German'))
```

the select of `to_date(beginn, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German')* and *to_date(ende, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German')` from dual works and i get MM/DD/YYYY for both

Comment: Are `beginn` and `ende` already Date datatype? If they are you can use EXTRACT function instead of TO_DATE.

Comment: oh sorry, no its varchar2

Comment: Please provide some sample data stored in these fields.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69271467/edit) to add that data as formatted text. Also is the view query doing its own conversion of strings to dates - using the session data language?

Comment: Regardless of your immediate question, do you realize that using `to_date` on month names, like you do, will **not** include the month of July, for example, if `ende` is `'Juli'`? `to_date` the way you call it will return July 1 of the current year, time 00:00:00 - which means that "between ... and ..." will be "between ... and July 1 at midnight" - leaving out anything in July (except exactly midnight on July 1).

Comment: With your six sample rows [it seems to be OK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b0988d6a3b08390e38704483c6de1774). If you have a lot more data really then do you get the expected output for all rows when you just query the view, or do only see for example just the first page of data in a result grid, like the (by default) first 50 rows in SQL Developer - but scrolling to the last row throws the error? I still suspect the view query is causing a problem, but you'd need to show that query and the underlying raw data, preferably for rows that do show an error.

Comment: @mathguy, yeah i realized this and its enough for me to handle it. my problem is, that i have some different values in the table like month names and season names ("translated" by case when to month names) It is not possible to store the values in a more granular way like date values

Comment: @AlexPoole, I don't have more than 6 rows. some of this rows are "translated" from season name to month name via case when

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are invalid months names in your table. Another proof that you should **never** store date/time values as string. Use always proper `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` data type.

If you use Oracle 18 or newer, then you can find invalid values like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM VIEW_USER_CON_PFLANZE_ERNTE
WHERE 
   TO_DATE(beginn DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German') IS NULL
   OR 
   TO_DATE(ende DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German') IS NULL
```

or this one:

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT beginn, ende,
       VALIDATE_CONVERSION(beginn AS DATE, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German') as begin_valid,
       VALIDATE_CONVERSION(ende AS DATE, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German') as end_valid
   FROM VIEW_USER_CON_PFLANZE_ERNTE)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE begin_valid= 0 or end_valid = 0
```

Comment: yes you are absolutly right. its not a good idea to store date as varchar2, but for now, i have no other choice. both of your scripts results in **no data found**

Comment: **EDIT:** if i use the underlying table in your scripts i get results. the validation of beginn and ende is 0. at the view i see only 1 (if i ignore your whereclause)

Answer (score 0):

It is really a bad practice to store `date` fields as `varchar2`. I have seen it many times and it is always a source for problems and issues.

Looking are your data sample, it looks to me like the reason why you got the error is because you really have invalid months in your data. I am not even considering that the "between" you are applying lacks of basic logic, as between should include both respectively. The reason is the conversion from `to_date` from a month that gives you the first day at midnight. Perhaps you should consider using `last_day` as well in order to include the data of the second month used in the between condition.

**Demonstration**

```
SQL>  create table t1 ( c1 varchar2(30) , c2 varchar2(30) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values ( 'JANUAR' , 'MAI' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values ( 'JANUAR' , 'FEBRUAR' );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1 ;

C1                             C2
------------------------------ ------------------------------
JANUAR                         MAI
JANUAR                         FEBRUAR
```

So, now we have two fields with `varchar2` data type but they contain the month in German Language. Applying your filter works perfectly

```
SQL> select to_date(c1,'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German' ) as c1 ,
  2  to_date(c2, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German' ) as c2,
  3  sysdate-180 as date_calculation
  4  from t1
  5   where sysdate-180 between  to_date(c1,'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German' )
  6* and to_date(c2, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=German' )
SQL> /

C1        C2        DATE_CALC
--------- --------- ---------
01-JAN-21 01-MAY-21 25-MAR-21
```

The only possible explanation is that you have indeed data which is not a valid month. You can use the answer provided by @Wernfried Domscheit to find out which rows don't contain valid months.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a57677b1d226208499cb77cd7adc6402)

Comment: sample data are now available :) sorry, I really thought in that case, that doesn't make any sense

Comment: With your data sample, it works without issues. So you have not valid months in your data. It is the only explanation.

Comment: my underlying table had some issues, not visible in the view. i fixed the issues and it works... g2k: just because the view works, the underlying table doesn't work, so you can't use a where between clause even if your view works

Comment: you will never see that in a view. A view is a logical construction, a select embedded in an object with no relation to the data until it is executed. your view will compile as long as the sql is valid, but it won't check the data until you make a select over it.

Answer (score 0):

okay my solution is simple... I found some exceptions in my field values of the **underlying table** and removed them... it works...

**learnings**

- just because the view works, the underlying table doesn't work, so you can't use a where between clause even if your view works
- if it not work, search for exception in your fields
- and don't use varchar2 for date comparison unless absolutely necessary